# TypeError: Assignment to constant variable. in ping command discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So I have this problem right now. So before, my ping command worked, but now it's not, here is the error:

```
(node:739) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
```

The thing is, I changed everything and there is no 'const', but anyways, here is the code.

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'ping',
  description: "Ping command lol",
  execute(message, args, client, Discord) {
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#29B721')
      .setTitle('Ping')
      .setDescription(`<a:loading:855847974521536512> Calculating ping...`)
    message.channel.send(embed).then((sentMessage) => {
      setTimeout(function() {
        let botPing = sentMessage.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp

        embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('#29B721')
          .setTitle('Ping')
          .setDescription(`<:online:855848500382269470> Ping: ${botPing}ms`)
        sentMessage.edit(embed)
      }, 1000);
    })
      .catch(console.error);
  }
}
```

EDIT: Ok so some people asked me if it was another file, but I don't think so. Anyways, here's my command handler:

```
client.on('message', async message => {
  let prefix = dprefix

  let pprofile = await prefixSchema.findOne({
    _id: message.guild.id
  })

  if (pprofile) prefix = pprofile.prefix

  let bprofile = await blacklistSchema.findOne({
    _id: message.author.id
  });

  if (bprofile) return message.channel.send(`:x: You have been blacklisted from this bot. You can't use this bot.`)

  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  if (message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  const command = client.commands.get(cmd);

  const premium_option = (command.premium)
  if (premium_option = true) {
    let checkprofile = await premiumSchema.findOne({
      _id: message.author.id
    })
    if (!checkprofile) return message.channel.send(`:x: You need Premium to use this command`)
  }

  if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
    cooldowns.set(command.name, new Collection());
  }

  const current_time = Date.now();
  const time_stamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
  const cooldown_amount = (command.cooldown) * 1000;

  if (time_stamps.has(message.author.id)) {
    const expiration_time = time_stamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldown_amount;

    if (current_time < expiration_time) {
      const time_left = (expiration_time - current_time) / 1000;

      return message.channel.send(`:x: You can't use this command yet. Wait ${time_left} seconds more.`)
    }
  }

  time_stamps.set(message.author.id, current_time);
  setTimeout(() => time_stamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldown_amount)

  try {
    command.execute(message, args, client, Discord);
  } catch (err) { 
    message.channel.send(`Error occured while executing the command. This command doesn't work or it doesn't exist.`) 
    console.log(`Error occured while executing command ${command.name}: ${err}`)
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct piece of code that gives you that error?

Comment: I think it is. If it was in the command handler it would have gave me a message in the console.

Comment: This code should run fine. You're not assigning anything to any constants.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? Can you look for that line in that file if you do?

Comment: No, I don't have a stack trace. And I know, it should run fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your command handler you have `if (premium_option = true)`. This single equals is assigning the existing constant value to `true` not comparing it. You want to use either double equals if you want to check truthy values, or tripple equals if you want to check the value is the boolean `true`.
i.e. `if (premium_option === true)`